# Matlab GUI table row

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to add data to a row of my created GUI table, however whenever I press the button the data is posted to the 5th row instead of the first one. When I create the table in GUI it already has 4 rows, I tried deleting them but they continue to appear.

```
data = get(handles.uitable1, 'data');   
k = size(data,1)+1; 

if k == 1
    B = num2cell(data);
else
    B = data;
end

B{k,1} = xrange;
B{k,2} = xmoment;
B{k,3} = xmad;
B{k,4} = xiqr;
B{k,5} = xstd;
B{k,6} = xvar;

set(handles.uitable1, 'data', B);
```

Since the table already has 4 rows, the size will be 4 and it will be incremented by 1 every time I press a button. Is there a way to start inserting the data at the first row and then incrementing it normally?
   You can look at how the data is inserted in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: I suspect your Data is just a cell of `NaN` values with 4 rows, if you already have the table. Try to find the first row with all NaN values and use that for k. You can use `isnan` and `all` functions for this

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the initialization of the table. If you want an empty table, insert this line

```
set(handles.uitable1,'data',{});
```

in the opening function of the GUI, `function myGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`.

You're right in that it seems trying to empty the table data in GUIDE is futile.

Comment: Thank you! But I've already figured it out! I have loaded a workspace variable which was empty, and now works wonderfully! Thank you again for your answer!